# how can I make snapchat ads charge you when user click a specific button

Tags: ads, snapchat

I need to make a snapchat ads with conversion that charge you when user click a specific button
like cost if user click on call button or whatsapp one ?

I have tried Page_view option .. but no good resutl

Comment: take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-database-snapshot-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16